# Launching multiple RDP sessions via powershell script

Tags: windows, powershell, rdp

Here is the script:

```
$compnames = import-csv "$env:userprofile\Documents\list.csv"
$User      = "username"
$Password  = "password"


foreach ($computer in $compnames) {
    cmdkey /generic:TERMSRV/$($computer.compname) /user:$User /pass:$Password
    mstsc /v:$($computer.compname)
}
```

When I run the script, I get the following error:

```
cmdkey : The term 'cmdkey' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again. At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\rdpsession\1.0.2\RdpSession.psm1:92 char:1
+ cmdkey /generic:Termsrv/$computer /user:$Username /pass:$rdp > $null
+ ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (cmdkey:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

mstsc : The term 'mstsc' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again. At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\rdpsession\1.0.2\RdpSession.psm1:94 char:1
+ mstsc /v:$computer
+ ~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (mstsc:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

It seems like powershell doesn't recognize cmdkey and mstsc. I've tried googling for hours with no solution. Hoping some one knows what the issue is here preventing the script from running.

Thanks!

Comment: In principal this works as if I copy/paste your code into a PowerShell window it works.  How are you invoking your script and what else happens in this file: `C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\rdpsession\1.0.2\RdpSession.psm1`

Comment: I am launching the .ps1 with powershell (right click->run with powershell)

Comment: Confirmed.  I've just done the same with your script and it works fine.  Perhaps try to uninstall the `rdpsession` module?  Have you tried your script on an alternative machine yourself?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the actual executables are in your path.

e.g.

```
dir "$($env:systemroot)\system32\cmdkey.exe"
dir "$($env:systemroot)\system32\mstsc.exe"
```

Answer (score 0):

The errors are specif.

> cmdkey : The term 'cmdkey' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet
>
> mstsc : The term 'mstsc' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

Those two items are external executables of the Windows and ran via cmd.exe, not PowerShell. Running executables/external commands in PowerShell is a well-documented thing, directly from Microsoft.

PowerShell only runs, '*.ps*' files. Executables are executed via cmd.exe, even from a PowerShell script, which will call cmd.exe under the covers to run them.

If you want to see your call stack of your command, that is why the ***Trace-Command*** cmdlet exists.

```
# Get specifics for a module, cmdlet, or function
(Get-Command -Name Trace-Command).Parameters
(Get-Command -Name Trace-Command).Parameters.Keys
Get-help -Name Trace-Command -Examples
Get-help -Name Trace-Command -Full
Get-help -Name Trace-Command -Online
```

> PowerShell: Running Executables
>
> https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7703.powershell-running-executables.aspx

As is PowerShell command precedence.

```
about_Command_Precedence

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_command_precedence?view=powershell-7

1 - Alias
2 - Function
3 - Cmdlet
4 - External executable files (programs and non-PowerShell scripts)
```

With your use case, the call operator is most prudent.

> 5. The Call Operator &
>
> Why: Used to treat a string as a SINGLE command. Useful for dealing with spaces.
>
> In PowerShell V2.0, if you are running 7z.exe (7-Zip.exe) or another command that starts with a number, you have to use the command invocation operator &.
>
> The PowerShell V3.0 parser does it now smarter, in this case, you don’t need the & anymore. >
> Details: Runs a command, script, or script block. The call operator, also known as the "invocation operator," lets you run commands that are stored in variables and represented by strings. Because the call operator does not parse the command, it cannot interpret command parameters
>
> Example:

```
& 'C:\Program Files\Windows Media Player\wmplayer.exe' "c:\videos\my home video.avi" /fullscreen
```

> Things can get tricky when an external command has a lot of parameters or there are spaces in the arguments or paths!
>
> With spaces, you have to nest Quotation marks and the result is not always clear!
>
> In this case it is better to separate everything like so:

```
$CMD = 'SuperApp.exe'
$arg1 = 'filename1'
$arg2 = '-someswitch'
$arg3 = 'C:\documents and settings\user\desktop\some other file.txt'
$arg4 = '-yetanotherswitch'
 
& $CMD $arg1 $arg2 $arg3 $arg4
```

or same like that:

```
$AllArgs = @('filename1', '-someswitch', 'C:\documents and settings\user\desktop\some other file.txt', '-yetanotherswitch')
& 'SuperApp.exe' $AllArgs
```

If the executable is not in your System path, or $env:PSModulePath, then you must provide the full path to the executable, as noted by the answer provided by ***'Dan'***.